# getSelection array values for MULTI Select list in Sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I don't know how to get the values of the MULTI select list.

I have tried to use the method `getSelection`; however, I'm getting an error that it's undefined.  Here's my code:

```
refs : {
    optionlist : 'Overlayitemlist',
},
var reco= Ext.getCmp('optionlist').getSelection() ;
```

Here's the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getSelection' of undefined

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`selectionchange`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-event-selectionchange) event to keep track of your multi selection and based on that, you can push all those values inside an array. Here is an example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    fullscreen: true,
    mode: 'MULTI',
    store: {
        fields: ['name'],
            data: [{
            name: 'Red'
        }, {
            name: 'Orange'
        }, {
            name: 'Yellow'
        }, {
            name: 'Green'
        }, {
            name: 'Blue'
        }] // data
    }, // store
     itemTpl: '{name}',
     listeners: {
         selectionchange: function (list, records) {
            var names = [];
            Ext.Array.each(records, function (item) {
                names.push('<li>' + item.data.name + '</li>');
            });
            Ext.Msg.alert('You selected ' + records.length + ' item(s)', '<ul>' + names.join('') + '</ul>');
         } 
     } 
});
```

Comment: records.length is always 1

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated example from Senhca's site ([link](http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/demos/Ext.List.mode/)). 
Apparently even their demo is not working properly.

```
/*global Ext:false */
Ext.application({
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.List', {
            fullscreen: true,
            mode: 'MULTI',
            store: {
                fields: ['name'],
                data: [{
                    name: 'Red'
                }, {
                    name: 'Orange'
                }, {
                    name: 'Yellow'
                }, {
                    name: 'Green'
                }, {
                    name: 'Blue'
                }] // data
            }, // store
            itemTpl: '{name}',
            listeners: {
                selectionchange: function (list, records) {
                    var names = [];
                    Ext.Array.each(list.selected.items, function (item) {
                        names.push('<li>' + item.data.name + '</li>');
                    }); // each()

                    Ext.Msg.alert('You selected ' + list.selected.items.length + ' item(s)');
                } // selectionchange
            } // listeners
        }); // create()
    } // launch
}); // application()
```